# Difference in the results of String comparison in Java?

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

How does Java implement the below string comparisons

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String a = "Chaipau";
        String b = "pau";

        System.out.println(a == "Chai"+"pau"); //true
        System.out.println(a == "Chai"+b); //false
    }
}
```

This is different from [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) , as the answer does not contain the why a new object is created in the second case , when it could have pointed to the same object reference as it is done in the first case.

Comment: Don't compare strings like that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: that's a referential comparison, don't expect it to behave like a comparison of values

Comment: Ya, but want to know how the results are obtained.

Comment: The == compares references, so the "numbers" that identify the two memory areas occupied by the objects. It is a 32 or 64 bit value depending on platform. In conclusion, the result is non deterministic, because it depends on memory actual state; that's the reason because == should not be used when comparing non-primitive types.

Comment: the first one is a constant and it is interned in the string constant pool, thus two references point to the same thing in the constant pool. the second one is not a constant, but you try to reference it from the constant pool, thus false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"Chai"+"pau"` is semantically identical to `"Chaipau"`, and thus is the same instance that `a` refers to.

`"Chai"+b` is evaluated at runtime (because `b` is not a compile-time constant expression), creating a new instance of `String`, and thus is not the same instance that `a` refers to.

Comment: Specifically, `"Chai"+"pau"` is a [compile-time constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28): "Constant expressions of type String are always "interned" so as to share unique instances"

Comment: Cool, as 
declaring final String b = "pau";
leaves the variable b to a compile time expression and the second case results to true.